# Implementing an immutable enumerator

Tags: c#, ienumerable, immutability, ienumerator

Consider the following possible interface for an immutable generic enumerator:

```
interface IImmutableEnumerator<T>
{
    (bool Succesful, IImmutableEnumerator<T> NewEnumerator) MoveNext();
    T Current { get; }
}
```

How would you implement this in a reasonably performant way in c#? I'm a little out of ideas, because the `IEnumerator` infrastructure in .NET is inherently mutable and I can't see a way around it.

A naive implementation would be to simply create a new enumerator on every `MoveNext()` handing down a new inner mutable enumerator with `current.Skip(1).GetEnumerator()` but that is horribly inefficient.

I'm implementing a parser that needs to be able to look ahead; using an immutable enumerator would make things cleaner and easier to follow so I'm curious if there is an easy way to do this that I might be missing.

The input is an `IEnumerable<T>` and I can't change that. I can always materialize the enumerable with `ToList()` of course (with an `IList` in hand, looking ahead is trivial), but the data can be pretty large and I'd like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: "that is horribly inefficient." - No, it's not. That's how immutability works. What makes you think it is "horribly inefficient"?

Comment: You're leaving out an important detail: how many items *exactly* do you need to look ahead? Because if it's one (as suggested by your `Skip(1)` snippet), this is trivially (although perhaps not "cleanly") achieved with a `foreach` loop which stores the iterator's `Current` value from the previous iteration in a local (declared outside the loop). If it's more than one, you can have a fixed-size buffer which will drop old items as it reaches capacity (Ix.NET's `Memoize` operates on this principle). Neither of these solutions are immutable, but then again one must wonder: do they *need* to be?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes it is, by the time I've advanced 1000 items, *every* enumerator will need to skip 1000 items just to reach the item I'm interested in. The amount of needless iterations skyrockets...

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy no, there is no need. I was merely wondering if I wasn't seeing and abvious way to achieve it. I'm almost convinced there is isn't, and buffering data was the obvious second choice. The amount of look ahead iterations is variable, it can be much more than 1.

Comment: @Enigmativity The key of the problem is that I don't see a way to create an immutable snapshot of the enumerator's state. So using `Skip` simply hands down a new enumeration *from scratch* with chained skips; `initial.Skip(1).Skip(1).....Skip(1)`. When you materialize any of these "new" enumerations, you will enumerate from the *begining*, not the last state.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't IEnumerator<T> immutable to begin with?  Look at the remarks section of the [`IEnumerator<T> Interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) msdn page: 
**Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.**

Comment: @ZoharPeled, enumerators in .NET are mutable by design. They almost never offer a way to change the underlying *collection* (which is what the spec you quoted says), but the enumerator objects *themselves* are only useful if they can be mutated (via the `MoveNext` call).

Comment: @InBetween - Surely `IImmutableEnumerator<T>` just has an internal enumerator that it just moves one by as it needs to? No need to repeatedly skip.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Ok, got it, thanks.

Comment: @InBetween - I think I've solved it.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, but the inner enumerator is the *same* for all immutable instances. If I move next one, I move next all. Do you understand?

Comment: @InBetween - No, that's not how this works. It only calls `.MoveNext()` when it creates a new `ImmutableEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

This is it:

```
public class ImmutableEnumerator<T> : IImmutableEnumerator<T>, IDisposable
{
    public static (bool Succesful, IImmutableEnumerator<T> NewEnumerator) Create(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        var successful = enumerator.MoveNext();
        return (successful, new ImmutableEnumerator<T>(successful, enumerator));
    }
    private IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    private (bool Succesful, IImmutableEnumerator<T> NewEnumerator) _runOnce = (false, null);
    private ImmutableEnumerator(bool successful, IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        _enumerator = enumerator;
        this.Current = successful ? _enumerator.Current : default(T);
        if (!successful)
        {
            _enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public (bool Succesful, IImmutableEnumerator<T> NewEnumerator) MoveNext()
    {
        if (_runOnce.NewEnumerator == null)
        {
            var successful = _enumerator.MoveNext();
            _runOnce = (successful, new ImmutableEnumerator<T>(successful, _enumerator));
        }
        return _runOnce;
    }
    public T Current { get; private set; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My test code succeeds nicely:

```
var xs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var ie = ImmutableEnumerator<int>.Create(xs);
if (ie.Succesful)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ie.NewEnumerator.Current);
    var ie1 = ie.NewEnumerator.MoveNext();
    if (ie1.Succesful)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ie1.NewEnumerator.Current);
        var ie2 = ie1.NewEnumerator.MoveNext();
        if (ie2.Succesful)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ie2.NewEnumerator.Current);
            var ie3 = ie2.NewEnumerator.MoveNext();
            if (ie3.Succesful)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ie3.NewEnumerator.Current);
                var ie4 = ie3.NewEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

It's immutable and it's efficient.

---

Here's a version using `Lazy<(bool, IImmutableEnumerator<T>)>` as per a request in the comments:

```
public class ImmutableEnumerator<T> : IImmutableEnumerator<T>, IDisposable
{
    public static (bool Succesful, IImmutableEnumerator<T> NewEnumerator) Create(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        var successful = enumerator.MoveNext();
        return (successful, new ImmutableEnumerator<T>(successful, enumerator));
    }
    private IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    private Lazy<(bool, IImmutableEnumerator<T>)> _runOnce;
    private ImmutableEnumerator(bool successful, IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        _enumerator = enumerator;
        this.Current = successful ? _enumerator.Current : default(T);
        if (!successful)
        {
            _enumerator.Dispose();
        }
        _runOnce = new Lazy<(bool, IImmutableEnumerator<T>)>(() =>
        {
            var s = _enumerator.MoveNext();
            return (s, new ImmutableEnumerator<T>(s, _enumerator));
        });
    }
    public (bool Succesful, IImmutableEnumerator<T> NewEnumerator) MoveNext()
    {
        return _runOnce.Value;
    }
    public T Current { get; private set; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @hvd - Yes, true.

Comment: I think this should take in `IEnumerator<T>` in the constructor (as opposed to `IEnumerable<T>`) so that `ImmutableEnumerator<T>` is not responsible for the enumerator's lifetime (right now enumerator's `Dispose` never gets called).

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy - I've now made a version with disposability. :-)

Comment: Looks good now. A suggestion: implement `MoveNext` using `Lazy<T>`. Slightly less code, and automatically thread-safe.

Comment: That's actually worse than it was before. You've created a situation where you *cannot* call `Dispose` on any enumerators except for the last one. And you *have to* get to the last one. If you break out early, the underlying mutable enumerator is never disposed. Letting the caller worry about disposing the enumerator is a far easier way out.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy - I did implement `IDisposable` on the entire class. It can be manually disposed of, which should be the correct way to go. It's a little flakey as you can dispose of any one of the instances to dispose of the underlying enumerator, so I could spend some time making it more robust.

Comment: @hvd - If I get a chance I'll try that.

Comment: @hvd - Done. It's the same amount of code, but the thread safety is a good bonus.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, i'll take a closer look but it definitely looks good.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve pseudo immutability suitable in this particular scenario by utilising a singly linked list. It allows for infinite look-ahead (limited only by your heap size) without the ability to look at previously processed nodes (unless you happen to store a reference to a previously processed node - which you shouldn't).

This solution addresses the requirements as stated (except for not conforming to your exact interface, with all of its functionality nevertheless intact).

The usage of such a linked list might look like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbersFromZeroToNine = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

using (IEnumerator<int> enumerator = numbersFromZeroToNine.GetEnumerator())
{
    var node = LazySinglyLinkedListNode<int>.CreateListHead(enumerator);

    while (node != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Current value: {node.Value}.");

        if (node.Next != null)
        {
            // Single-element look-ahead. Technically you could do node.Next.Next...Next.
            // You can also nest another while loop here, and look ahead as much as needed.
            Console.WriteLine($"Next value: {node.Next.Value}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End of collection reached. There is no next value.");
        }

        node = node.Next;

        // At this point the object which used to be referenced by the "node" local
        // becomes eligible for collection, preventing unbounded memory growth.
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Current value: 0.
Next value: 1.
Current value: 1.
Next value: 2.
Current value: 2.
Next value: 3.
Current value: 3.
Next value: 4.
Current value: 4.
Next value: 5.
Current value: 5.
Next value: 6.
Current value: 6.
Next value: 7.
Current value: 7.
Next value: 8.
Current value: 8.
Next value: 9.
Current value: 9.
End of collection reached. There is no next value.
```

The implementation is as follows:

```
sealed class LazySinglyLinkedListNode<T>
{
    public static LazySinglyLinkedListNode<T> CreateListHead(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        return enumerator.MoveNext() ? new LazySinglyLinkedListNode<T>(enumerator) : null;
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    private IEnumerator<T> Enumerator;
    private LazySinglyLinkedListNode<T> _next;

    public LazySinglyLinkedListNode<T> Next
    {
        get
        {
            if (_next == null && Enumerator != null)
            {
                if (Enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    _next = new LazySinglyLinkedListNode<T>(Enumerator);
                }
                else
                {
                    Enumerator = null; // We've reached the end.
                }
            }

            return _next;
        }
    }

    private LazySinglyLinkedListNode(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        Value = enumerator.Current;
        Enumerator = enumerator;
    }
}
```

An important thing to note here is that the source collection is only enumerated *once*, lazily, with `MoveNext` being called at most once per each node's lifetime regardless of how many times you access `Next`.

Using a doubly-linked list would allow look-behind, but would cause infinite memory growth and require periodic pruning, which is not trivial. Singly-linked list avoids this issue as long as you are not storing node references outside of your main loop. In the example above you could replace `numbersFromZeroToNine` with an `IEnumerable<int>` generator which infinitely yields integers, and the loop will run forever without running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why I shouldn't keep a reference to past nodes. The whole point of looking ahead is that I must make a decision on a past node based upon a future one. If I don't keep a reference to the past node, I can't make the decision. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: No problem, I'll try to clarify. Your interface only provides a `MoveNext` method, so the assumption is that you'll never need to iterate backwards. If, however, *while* you're iterating through your source collection (using a loop of some kind and calling `MoveNext` on each immutable enumerator to produce the next enumerator reference), you need to "peek" a few (or a few thousand) elements ahead to see what's next, both mine and Enigmativity's implementations allow you to do that efficiently.

Comment: My point re not storing references to enumerators/nodes outside of your main loop came about because you mentioned not wanting to materialise your large source collection (via `ToList`). If you're holding a strong reference to the head node in my example (or the first iterator in Enigmativity's one), you are causing that exact situation: *all* the elements you've looped through stay in memory forever (remember: each element points to the next one, it's a chain). If some old element can't be collected, none of the elements that follow will be collected either.

Comment: So the trick to keeping memory in check is to loop through your source collection using a loop similar to the while example I've posted, peeking as many elements immediately following the current one as necessary (using `node.Next.Next.Next` or `enumerator.MoveNext().MoveNext()`) - but never storing old node/enumerator references outside of your loop longer than necessary.